# What is the best practice for passing object reference to different methods?

Tags: java, android, object, reference

First, I would like to thank you in advance for reading/answering my first question on stack overflow. I am new to java (android studio) and struggling a bit with understanding all these objects…

I am building my first app and I have created a new class to store and handle some Tile properties.

What I want, is to instantiate the object once then use a reference to that object and I will pass it to other methods for changing the data inside TileProperties. (I believe this is a good optimization of the memory usage)

I have tried a few solutions that I found but couldn’t make them work fully or couldn’t understand the code.

Here is what I did, which works now but I am wondering if it’s the best practice and also if it's a good option for the future:

```
public class TileProperties {

private String length ;
private String width ;
public  static TileProperties object; // I created a static object TileProperties 
                                    // which I use to pass the reference 

public String getLength() {
    return length;
}
public void setLength(String length) {
    this.length = length;
}
```

The code below shows my activity class where the user enters all the properties
Also, its where I initiate my object Tiles

```
public class TileSettingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TileProperties tiles = new TileProperties();

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tile_setting);
}

public void clickOkButton (View view) {

  TileProperties.object = tiles; // save the object reference tiles to be used by others
  EditText lengthTile = findViewById(R.id.editText2);
  tiles.setLength(lengthTile.getText().toString());
  Log.i("Length:", tiles.getLength());

}
```

And then in my main activity I wrote this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 public void clickScanButton(View view){

    TileProperties obj ; // define object reference 
    obj = TileProperties.object; // get the reference of the orginal object Tiles      
    Log.i("info:", obj.getLength());
}
```

Thank you!!

Comment: try looking up singleton pattern

Comment: Please lose the coloured pictures. Post text as text.

Comment: [There is no best practice.](https://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/5164)

Answer (score 1):

No this is not "best practice".  It is not even "good practice".  It is arguably wrong.  Certainly it would be wrong in a larger application.

Let's start with this class:

```
public class TileProperties {

private String length ;
private String width ;
public  static TileProperties object; // I created a static object TileProperties 
                                    // which I use to pass the reference 

public String getLength() {
    return length;
}
public void setLength(String length) {
    this.length = length;
}
}
```

In order of *least important to most important*, the problems are:

1. There are various style issues.  The most important are that the indentation is incorrect and your choice of `object` for a variable name is bad.  Variable names should convey relevant meaning to the reader.
2. Documentation.  The comment `// I created a static object ...` should be a proper javadoc comment, that describes the purpose of this (`public` !) variable.
3. Public variables break encapsulation and encourage excessive coupling.  They are not Object Oriented.  They should be avoided.
4. Public `static` variables are worse because they *also* represent global state.

If you are going to implement a single shared "properties" object for the application, there are three ways to do it.

- You can create a single instance of the class and pass it as a parameter to all of the parts of the application that need it.  This can be clumsy if you have to pass the reference to lots of places.
- You can use the [Singleton design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).  A simple example for your use-case would be:

  ```
    public class TileProperties {
        // state variables

        private static TileProperties instance = new TileProperties();

        private TileProperties() { }  // This prevents creation of multiple
                                      // instances of the "singleton"

        public static TileProperties getInstance() {
            return instance;
        }

        // getters and setters for state variables, etc.
    }

    // In main

    TileProperties props = TileProperties.getInstance();
    props.setLength(42);
  ```

  There are other ways to implement singletons in Java; e.g. if the singleton needs to be initialized lazily.
- Use [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) (DI).

Dependency injection is considered to be superior to Singleton classes in large-scale applications because singletons present problems for unit testing.  However, DI requires a framework such as Spring to implement the injection.  That is a whole new learning curve.